# Почему не отображается линия красного цвета?

Tags: svg

```html
<svg>
  <line x1='20' y1='80' x2='140' y2='80' stroke-width='5' fill='red'/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У линии нечего "заполнять" - `fill`.

```html
<svg>
  <line x1='20' y1='80' x2='140' y2='80' stroke-width='5' stroke='red'/>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg stroke='black'>
  <line x1='20' y1='80' x2='140' y2='80' stroke-width='5' />
</svg>
```

Comment: получилось скажите если убрать stroke='red' то line  по умолчанию должна стать черного цвета ?

Comment: @Leks Сколько секунд нужно, чтобы это выяснить?

Comment: около 15-20 минут когда чайник поставишь кипятится, его снимешь, сделаешь чай и так далее, а у Вас получилось за несколько секунд справится  ... :))